# No matching function for call to...?

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error for what I assume is declaring the incorrect type, but I'm not sure where the issue is or what I need to fix. I'm using two files.

Please tell me if I haven't given enough info, I'm still a newbie. I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: Probably worth showing the code that the error message actually refers to.

Comment: Seems like you should have an empty constructor in there.

Comment: "I believe the error occurs on the 7th line of my zillow.cpp file below." - Don't "believe", read the error message carefully and it tells you exactly where it came from and what is wrong.

Comment: The Mirmir system is executing a program that tests on the code, I am not able to see the code for this correction. I have added the input that was given through the test at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Nothing do do with your error, but it would be much clearer (not just here, but for you and your colleagues) to put a class called HousePrice in files called HousePrice, rather than zillow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate you can't change the input for the test, but whoever wrote the test needs to be told it's a bad test.

Data should be initialized through a constructor.

Data members (`address` and `price`) should be declared as private not public.

Whoever wrote the test is requiring you to write a bad C++ class.

That said, you can conform with this bad test by adding to the .h file:

```
HousePrice();
```

and to the .cpp file

```
HousePrice::HousePrice():address(""),price(0){}
```

Thereby giving it the expected default constructor.

Comment: Well, it would be better to fix the test which is the real problem, but if you're happy, do mark it as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
#include "zillow.h"
HousePrice hp ("1600 Pen. Ave",1561.53);
ASSERT_EQ(hp.price, 1561.53);
```

Previously you were trying to create your `HousePrice` object with no constructor parameters, but the only constructor you've written takes `address` and `price`.

Comment: OP is submitting code to some testing system and can't change that part.

Comment: I am not able to change the input, the system asserts it on it's own.

Comment: So who wrote what you have labelled 'Here is the input for the test case'?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message. You are trying to default-construct an object of  `HousePrice` type, but `HousePrice` does not have a default constructor.

Add a default constructor (a constructor with no parameters)

Side note: there is no point in having getter or setter functions in this example. Your data members are public and you don't have any constraints on them

Answer (score 0):

**The error is here:**

`HousePrice hp;`

When you create an object of a class like that, the default constructor of the class is invoked implicitly. But your class definition does not have a **default constructor**.

**Solution:**

Since you are not allowed to change the code at the caller's part, you should modify your class definition such that it contains a default constructor. Then it is upto you to decide the initial values or simply leave it empty.

*For example:*

Add `HousePrice()` inside the class definition in zillow.h

Add the following into zillow.cpp

```
HousePrice::HousePrice()
{
    address = "";
    price = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Should use initializer list.

Comment: Initializer lists have been around since C++ 98 (and earlier). I'm talking about `ctor::ctor():member(val){}`, not `vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4};`

Comment: @JasperKent Oh, you mean that. The code should work fine either ways. Will it work for `double`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'Will it work for double?'

Comment: @JasperKent That was just a doubt before the edit you made to your answer. Also, you should not downvote others' answers just to get your answer to the top. Or, let me know why was this answer downvoted?

Comment: Because you didn't use the member initializer list.